# Google chrome app redirects

Tags: applications, google-chrome, google

When i try to download the google chrome app on my iphone or ipad, it redirects me to a page that says it will download the app...but jus keeps redirecting and wont load. How do i get it to load?

Comment: You are downloading it from the AppStore ? I never heard of any download button that redirects anyone anywhere.

Comment: It wont download in the app store. It looks like a "fake page" that goes nowhere and does nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you might have bigger problems than downloading Google Chrome. Is the iPhone/iPad jailbroken? Doesn't sound like you are accessing the real AppStore.

Comment: Why yes I think it is. I did a factory reset, but that did not solve my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably are going to the Google Chrome desktop website, which will "download" a .app or .exe. Open the iOS App Store, search "Chrome", then download it from there.